# VM Scaleset not scaling

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VM Scale set (which is used for Service Fabric) and I am applying some rules on CPU average and I cannot achieve to do the auto scale up. I even tried to put a CPU of 1% average and still not working. This is the criteria:

Time aggregation: Average
Metric name: Percentage CPU
Operator: Greater than
Threshold: 1
Duration (in minutes):5

Operation:Increase count by
Instance count: 1
Cool down (minutes): 5

The scale set has 5 VM and a limit of 7.

And of course the average percentage is above 1% always.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can consider the following things when you troubleshoot autoscale with VMSS:

> - If you’re using a VM bigger than a single-vCPU VM size like Standard_A1 or D1, you’d need to run this load multiple times.
> - A scale-out event only takes place when the average CPU across all the VMs in a scale set exceeds the threshold value, over the time
>     interval defined in the autoscale rules.
> - Are your scale-in and scale-out thresholds sufficiently different? ...

You can get more details from this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-troubleshoot).

Comment: Yes everything is verified according to the doc...I made another rule scaling out at 25% and scaling out at 10%. And stressed all the set (every machine) with a program, and I have an average of 30%...Nevertheless same result...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the REST API to see what values autoscale is calculating for your scale set. If these values are still above your threshold, then double-check that you haven't fallen into configuration pitfalls ("flapping" scenarios where a scale-out would cause an immediate scale-in, targetResourceUri is actually the resource you want (which may be different from the metricResourceUri), cooldown isn't excessively long, etc.).

I wrote up a quick blog post showing how to go about this: https://negatblog.wordpress.com/2018/08/22/debugging-azure-autoscale/. Hopefully this helps! :)